# How to insert a row with an incremental value in MySQL from data generated by a List and MySQL

Tags: python, mysql, list

I have a set of data from a retrieval from two sources (List and MySQL).

For example:

```
print(d)

((1L, ‘3333333’),  (1L, ‘4444444’), (2L, ‘6547837), (3L, ‘2222222’), (1L, ‘4565432’))
```

These are data I am trying to utilize for the next step (inserting a 
new row after increment of current value).

Bottom is my code to generate matching of two data sources:

MRNMatch1 is a name of list (generated for first source of data).

```
con = MySQLdb.connect(“localhost”, “username ”, “pwd”, “databasename”)
c = con.cursor()
sql = ‘select  course_num, mrn from Courses where mrn in (‘ + ‘,’.join(map(str, MRNMatch1)) + ‘)’
c.execute(sql)
d = c.fetchall()
print(d)
```

What I am trying to do is inserting a new row of data increment by 1 to 'course_num' column at MySQL.

For example, final output of updated data would be like:

```
((2L, ‘3333333’), (2L, ‘4444444’), (3L, ‘6547837), (4L, ‘2222222’), (2L, ‘4565432’))
```

How do I go about doing it?

Comment: Is 2L a string?

Comment: The data type is Long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
d=(('2L', '3333333'), ('2L', '4444444'), ('3L', '6547837'), ('4L', '2222222'), ('2L', '4565432'))
b=tuple(((str(int(elem[0][0])+1)+elem[0][1],elem[1]) for elem in d))
```

Just don't use curly quotes.

Comment: It says "TypeError: 'long' object has no attribute '__getitem__'  "